# Naming Convention for Property Name that has a Dot

Tags: naming-conventions

Is there a naming convention for a property/variable that has a dot/decimal in the name of the thing that the property/variable represents?

For example:

A class has a property that represents a 2.5 volt battery. Since we can't name the property/variable as "2.5VoltBattery" (the idea being that we can't have the decimal point in the name), I have always used the convention "2Point5VoltBattery" (replace the dot with the word Point).

I'm curious if there is a naming convention for this.

Comment: Different languages have different naming conventions.

Comment: @AaronMcIver - Convert your comment into an answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; it is preferential and will vary by team preference more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Battery_2_5_Volts`. Not sure whether is exact naming convention. To me it feels as a relevant one.